# Stamp in Masonry is not working on appended pages

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

Using **desandro.masonry**, I have a stamp that I want to show up on each page:

```
.stamp {
    position: absolute;
}

.stamp1 {
    margin: 5px;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

This works fine for the first page when I render photos 1-20, but when the second page is appended to the container (photos 21-40), it stops working. The second stamp is placed very close to the first stamp, overlapping photos from the first page.

This is the initial script that styles the first paginated page of photos:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
    var $box = $('.box');
    $box.hide();
    var $container = $('#masonry-container').masonry(); 
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $box.fadeIn();
      $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 10,
        gutterWidth: 0, 
        isAnimated : true,
        resizeable: true,
        itemSelector: '.box',
        stamp: '.stamp',
        fitWidth: true,
      });
    });
});
```

This is my homemade infinite scrolling that triggers the next_page.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
if($('#masonry-scrolling').size() > 0) {
      $('.pagination').hide();
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
       var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
       if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60 && $.active == 0) { $.getScript(url) }
    });
    }
});
```

This is the index.js.erb - this is a Rails app, this is ajax in Rails triggered from the above script:

```
var $boxes = $('<%= escape_javascript render :partial  => "photos/masonry"  %>')
var $container = $('#masonry-container')

$boxes.imagesLoaded(function() {
$container.append($boxes).masonry('appended', $boxes);
});

<% if @photos.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@photos) %>');
  $('.pagination').hide();
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %> 

_masonary.html.erb

<div class="stamp stamp1"> </div>
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="mimage">
      <%= link_to(image_tag(photo.picture.insta.url), photo_path(photo)) %>  
    </div>
  </div>  
<% end %>

index.html.erb (example.com/photos)

<div id="masonry-container">
 <%= render :partial => "photos/masonry" %>
</div>
<div id="masonry-scrolling">
<%= will_paginate @photos %>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the problem that you've not waited for the images to finish loading? This problem is common enough that it's covered with a solution on the masonry website as [the first FAQ item](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html).

Comment: No, I am using imagesLoaded and the photos all work find and are appended fine. i think the problem is the css and i dont know how to work around it.

Comment: Please post your code, not just your css, since this involves appending and laying out masonry after appending, otherwise its a total guess.

Comment: I edited more code into the question. thanks.